# Is saying that something which is haram is halal kufr?

Tags: halal-haram, kufr

Is saying that something which is haram is halal kufr?

The motivation for this question arose when I was speaking with my uncle who was talking to me about birthdays. He was telling me that I should go to birthdays and pray for the person who has a birthday because it is the intention that Allah (Glory be to Him, the most High) sees. I knew that celebrating birthdays is haram but I was trying to avoid arguing with him. So I said yes to him to avoid any further arguments. Have I become one of those who consider the haram halal?

Comment: First of all, **"I knew that celebrating birthdays is haram but I was trying to avoid arguing with him."**
- How did you know this? 

Not everybody agree that it's haram.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/notes/islamic-studies/evolution-of-birthday-celebration-islamic-ruling/162126440519824/  and https://islamqa.info/en/1027

Answer (score 2):

### In The Name of Allah, The Most Beneficent, The Most Merciful.

No, you didn't become one of those who consider the haram halal. What you did is, you lied. More specifically, you lied to reconcile between you and your uncle. In that case, lying is permissible. The evidence for that is found in the following hadith.

> Humaid b. 'Abd al-Rahman b. 'Auf reported that his mother Umm Kulthum
> daughter of 'Uqba b. Abu Mu'ait, and she was one amongst the first
> emigrants who pledged allegiance to Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon
> him), as saying that she heard Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon
> him) as saying: A liar is not one who tries to bring reconciliation
> amongst people and speaks good (in order to avert dispute), or he
> conveys good.
>
> Ibn Shihab said he did not hear that exemption was granted in anything
> what the people speak as lie but in three cases: in battle, **for
> bringing reconciliation amongst persons** and the narration of the words
> of the husband to his wife, and the narration of the words of a wife
> to her husband (in a twisted form in order to bring reconciliation
> between them).
>
> [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/130)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that a thing is "kufr" is not as easy as you seem to think. Even "kufr" is not as big word as you seem to think, as there is "the minor kufr" and "the major one", the first do not get you out of Islam, the second yes, but only if you insist on it after the truth has been revealed to you (Kitab or Sunna). What you said is by no mean a major kufr, nor à minor one I think, just a mistake, it would have been better to keep quite. Anyway, door of tawba is open, a good deed erases the bad one.

Comment: Nice brief answer. (it would be better if you could add ref. , anyhow well done mate.

Answer (score -3):

Short answers: Yes. KUFR means covering the truth with lies. KUFR is strictly forbidden.

Answer (score -4):

the prophet peace be upon him said this is haram so for anyone to say its halal is saying that the prophet is wrong and going against the prophet peace be upon him. the quran says we must obey our parents but not to obey them then they start telling u things that go against your deen. may allah bless and guide you.

Comment: No, the Prophet did not say it's haram nor does the Qur'an say we must obey our parents but it is haram to say things about Allah that you do not know 7:33.

Comment: -1, This statement is very wrong: "the prophet peace be upon him said this is haram so for anyone to say its halal is saying that the prophet is wrong and going against the prophet peace be upon him. "